'wave' pattern in ggpattern is not working
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)
ToothGrowth$dose<- factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(dose)) +
geom_bar_pattern(aes(fill=dose, pattern=dose, pattern_type=dose),colour='black') +
theme_bw() +
labs(title = "Use 'stripe' and 'wave' patterns") +
theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.5, 'cm')) +
scale_pattern_manual(values=c('stripe', 'wave', 'wave')) +
scale_pattern_type_manual(values=c(NA, 'triangle', 'sine'))


I try to fill the bar chart with "wave" pattern, but it does not work. On the ggpattern website.
https://trevorldavis.com/R/ggpattern/dev/articles/patterns-stripes.html#printscreenmixing-patterns ,
Similarly the mixing patterns section does not work, too.

sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.utf8 
#> [2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.utf8   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.utf8
#> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                               
#> [5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.utf8    
#> 
#> time zone: Asia/Shanghai
#> tzcode source: internal
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] digest_0.6.37     fastmap_1.2.0     xfun_0.47         glue_1.7.0       
#>  [5] knitr_1.48        htmltools_0.5.8.1 rmarkdown_2.28    lifecycle_1.0.4  
#>  [9] cli_3.6.3         reprex_2.1.1      withr_3.0.1       compiler_4.4.1   
#> [13] rstudioapi_0.16.0 tools_4.4.1       evaluate_0.24.0   yaml_2.3.10      
#> [17] rlang_1.1.4       fs_1.6.4

Created on 2024-09-25 with reprex v2.1.1
By adding pattern_frequency = 5, i solve the problem.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)
ToothGrowth$dose <- factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(dose)) +
    geom_bar_pattern(
        aes(
            fill = dose,
            pattern = dose,
            pattern_type = dose
        ),
        pattern_frequency = 5,
        colour = 'black'
    ) +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(title = "Use 'stripe' and 'wave' patterns") +
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.5, 'cm')) +
    scale_pattern_manual(values = c('stripe', 'wave', 'wave')) +
    scale_pattern_type_manual(values = c(NA, 'triangle', 'sine'))

This is  the expected output what i want


I can't reproduce this. The code works on my machine, giving the expected output. Are you able to include your OS details and the plotting device you are using in your question please?

try providing the  pattern_frequency to geom_col_pattern(). For example:
pattern_frequency = 5

@MichielDuvekot Post that comment as an answer?

@Michiel Duvekot Thank you.It works.

@Allan Cameron  Thank you.I added the session Information.
